# Symfony/PHPUnitClass 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I created a very simple basic api with the api-platform framework.
Now I am trying to write a simple unit test with PHP unit but when I try to run the test I keep getting this error:

`Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase' not found`

It is complaining about this line:

`class JobControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

It says `undefined class`

I installed phpunit with composer I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my full test:

```
<?php
namespace tests\AppBundle;

class JobControllerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPOST()
    {
        $client = new Client('http://localhost:8000', array(
            'request.options' => array(
                'exceptions' => false,
            )
        ));

        $data = array(
            'bar' => "hello",
        );

        $request = $client->post('/foos', null, json_encode($data));
        $response = $request->send();

        $this->assertEquals(201, $response->getStatusCode());
        $this->assertTrue($response->hasHeader('Location'));
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(true), true);
        $this->assertArrayHasKey('bar', $data);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me any bit that would be pretty cool :)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: It is because you have phpunit v6 installed.  Install v5 or v4 and you should be good to go.  There is actually quite a bit of discussion on this.

Comment: @Cerad I saw it on GitHub :) Thanks for letting me know though!

Comment: @Cerad Do you perhaps know why the ```$client = new Client(``` doesn't work? I did a composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle but doesn't seem to be working :p

Comment: Have you looked at the chapter on testing?  Client is a HttpFoundation class, not the guzzle class.

Comment: You can try to use the approach from the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811164/class-phpunit-framework-testcase-not-found/42828632#42828632 answer to be prepared for `PHPUnit 6` as well as for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

This is because on phpunit6 has been deprecated, use the following:

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends TestCase
```